# How to inject data in server-side from createServerRender?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I've been reading some tutorials but none so far are deep enough (or new enough) to show how to actually pass the data to a component. This is the farthest I could get:

In `boot.server.ts`:

```
export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        // default providers here
        { provide: 'MYDATA', useValue: params.data.myData }
    ];
    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
      // default implementation
    });
```

In a component:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent
{
    constructor(@Inject("MYDATA") myData: string) { }
}
```

But this fails with `No provider for 'MYDATA'!`

I was able to get the data into the `window` but this obviously doesn't work at `server-side`.
I am not sure whether I need to add `MYDATA` as a provider in `app.module.server.ts` and if so how that's done.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough information. Is `providers` actually used?

Comment: @estus I've updated the question to show how `providers` is used. `default implementation` is what the ASP.NET Core 2 Angular template creates

Comment: Looks ok. I'd expect it to work. It's unclear why the error is there. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem, e.g. a github repo.

Comment: @estus I'm working on an open-source project, you can find it [here](https://github.com/CamiloTerevinto/InstituteManager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading this from the future (~2018) then use [`TransferState`](https://next.angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState) instead.

---

Looks like you have this error on the client side. You probably forgot to specify provider for the `MYDATA` for the client side. I normally do this in *app.module.browser.ts* (previously named *app.module.client.ts*)
For example like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppSharedModule
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'MYDATA', useFactory: getMyData }
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}

/**
 * reads state from the dom generated on the server side
 */
export function getMyData()
{
    const appState = document.querySelector("app-state");
    if (appState)
    {
        return JSON.parse(appState.textContent!);
    }
    return null;
}
```

To save your server side state you can use the following technique:

```ts
import { Component, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-state',
    template: '{{state|json}}'
})
/** state component*/
export class StateComponent 
{
    state: any;

    /** state ctor */
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: any)
    {
        if (isPlatformServer(platformId))
        {
            this.state = {
                prop: "some state determined on the server side"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your app.component.html you can put state component like this or add condition to skip it on the client side:

```html
<app-state></app-state>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do it? I tried and got an error like `could not find a provider for string` or something like that

Comment: The thing is, I wanted to pass the data from server to browser, without having to get the data again once on the browser (hence `getMyData` doesn't make sense to me). Is this possible? I ended up injecting the window and reading the value from there

Comment: I personally do write data to the special component on the server side and then read it on the client side.
I will put an example in my answer. With your version of angular it is the only way. But they already committed a new thing that will do it for you. But it is almost the same thing and it will be easy to switch to there solution in the future.